# Which form events occur when Form.Requery is called?

Tags: ms-access, vba

[This Microsoft Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Order-of-events-for-database-objects-E76FBBFE-6180-4A52-8787-CE86553682F9) details the order of events that occur when a form is opened, gets focus etc. but doesn't clarify exactly what happens when a form/subform is requeried. The [MSDN page for Form.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193159(v=office.15).aspx) confirms this event as occurring on a refresh or requery, but are any other events also triggered?

Comment: Mostly the event you want is Current, Open is not a good event for controls.

Comment: (Aside : http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/order-of-events-for-database-objects-HP005186761.aspx )

Comment: @Fionnuala I've seen that particular article before but it wasn't clear to me whether it applied to Requery or just the form being opened initially. Current is sounding like a good candidate at the moment though. If Current triggers on `.Requery` then that would make a good answer although I'd prefer to know the full order of events for future reference ;)

Comment: The whole point of a continuous form is that the record that has focus is the current record, all other records are just echos, so anything that happens to the current record happens to all images.

Comment: The Current event will occur on requery. Load and Open events will not occur. Note that a number of events will not occur with programmatic changes.

Answer (score -2):

Taken from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191903.aspx

> ### The Requery method does one of the following:
>
> - Reruns the query on which the form or control is based.
> - Displays any new or changed records or removes deleted records from the table on which the form or control is based.
> - Updates records displayed based on any changes to the Filter property of the form.

Comment: This just explains what the requery method does. I know that already, I need to know which events e.g. `form.Current()` occur when `.reuqery` is used.

Comment: Alright, I put a `Debug.Print` on every form event.  Pressed a button that only does `Me.Requery`.  The only thing that came up in the immediate window was "Form_Current".

Comment: If you requery a subform from a parent form, Form_Current doesn't get fired on the subform.